# Need plain english translation of the following scala snippet

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and the playframework.  Can somebody please translate the following snippet below into plain english?  For context its found here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaSecurity

```
/**
 * This method shows how you could wrap the withAuth method to also fetch your user
 * You will need to implement UserDAO.findOneByUsername
 */
def withUser(f: User => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = withAuth { username => implicit request =>
  UserDAO.findOneByUsername(username).map { user =>
    f(user)(request)
  }.getOrElse(onUnauthorized(request))
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you are getting votes to close the question. I think your question is perfectly legitimate. I had myself seen that code before and was wondering how it worked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Part 1: First let's address the curried syntax:**

`withUser` is a method that takes a curried function `f` of type `User => Request[AnyContent] => Result`. It takes a `User` object and returns another function that takes a `Request` and returns a `Result`. Breaking it down, if `f` is that function then:

```
val g = f(user) // g is a function
val result = g(request) // returns a result
// same as:
val result = f(user)(request)
```

Practically speaking `f` is just like a function that takes two parameters but instead of calling `f(a, b)` you call `f(a)(b)`.

`withAuth` is also a method that takes a curried function. It has almost the same type as `withUser`.

**Part 2: Now how do you use those methods:**

As explained [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaActions), play makes you defined your application logic by telling it how to transform `Request` objects into `Result` objects.

`withAuth` is a helper function that takes care of the authentication for you and conveniently retrieves the username. So you use it like this:

```
def index = withAuth { username => implicit request =>
  Ok(html.index(username))
}
```

It returns a function that takes a `Request` and returns a `Result`, which is what play needs. But what it takes is a curried function (that takes a username) and return a function (that takes a request). The request parameter is marked as *implicit* so it can be passed implicitly to any function/method call that needs an implicit request parameter. For the purpose of this explanation, just ignore the `implicit` keyword.

**Part 3: Translation of `withUser`**

Well, its signature is similar to `withAuth` and the goal is for it to be used in the same way except the first parameter will be a `User` instead of a `String`. So it has to take a `User => Request => Result`. The request trait takes a type parameter which indicates the type of its content. Here it is `AnyContent`. So the correct type for the argument of `withUser` is `User => Request[AnyContent] => Result`. That means you will be able to use it like this:

```
withUser { user => implicit request =>
  // do something with user and request to return a result
}
```

If you look at the definition of `withUser`, all it does is to call `withAuth`:

```
def withUser(f: User => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = withAuth { 
  // ...
}
```

So it will return the same type as `withAuth` which means it will return a function that turns a `Request` into a `Result` (see Part 2 above). Which means we will be able to use it like this:

```
def index = withUser { user => implicit request => 
  Ok(html.index(user))
}
```

What is passed as an argument of `withAuth` is a curried function. I introduced intermediate `val` so that you can follow the types:

```
username => // first param is the username as a String
  implicit request => // second param is the request
    // here we have to return a Result...
    // we lookup the user - we may not have one:
    val userOption: Option[User] = UserDAO.findOneByUsername(username)
    // f is the code block that will be provided inside withUser { f }
    // Part 1 explains the f(user)(request) syntax
    // We call f to get a result, in the context of the Option monad
    val resultOption: Option[Result] = userOption.map(user => f(user)(request))
    // if we have a result, return it; otherwise return an error.
    resultOption.getOrElse(onUnauthorized(request))
```