# Understanding a Scala function from Play framework zentask example

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

This is a function in the zentask example in Application.scala.
I'm trying to understand it...

What does the f:  => String mean?

What about the chaining of f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result

```
/** 
 * Action for authenticated users.
 */
def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = 
       Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
       Action(request => f(user)(request))
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this other question/answer and see if yours is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653873/need-plain-english-translation-of-the-following-scala-snippet/13656978#13656978. I went to some length to explain a similar example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A parameter of the form `fn: => String` represents a 'generator' (either a function or a value) that returns (or is) a String, so, for example, you might have a method defined as

```
def myMethod(fn: => String): String = "Fn output = " + fn
```

and call this as follows (the return types I use here can typically be inferred by the compiler, I'm just adding them for pedagogical purposes):

```
def myFn: String = "Hello!"
// Alternatively: def myFn(): String = "Hello!"
// or: val myFn: () => String = "Hello!"
// or most simply: val myString = "Hello!"

val output = myMethod(myFn) // output = "Fn output = Hello!"
```

Building on this, we can define a method that takes a function that turns a String into an Int, eg:

```
def my2ndMethod(fn: String => Int): Int = fn("4")
```

and call it as follows:

```
def my2ndFn(input: String) = 5 * input.toInt
// Alternatively: val my2ndFn: String => Int = input => 5 * input.toInt

val output2 = my2ndMethod(my2ndFn _) // output2 = 20
```

In the case you provide, you have a more complicated entity: something that returns (or is) a function that takes a String and returns a further function that in turn takes a `Request[AnyContent]` and (finally) returns a Result (phew!).

You can also think of this as taking a function defined and used as follows:

```
def authFn(username: String)(request: Request[AnyContent]): Result

val authenticatedResult = IsAuthenticated(authFn _)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the 'pass by name' convention.  One other question:  what's the purpose of the underscore in my2ndMethod(my2ndFn _) ?

Comment: @seand - for the purpose of the underscore, see my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873870/convert-unit-to-unit/17874244#17874244). Essentially, it tells the compiler to pass the function in as the parameter, not the result of evaluating it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is a bit tricky to figure out how the operator associates:

```
f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result
```

is the same as

```
f: (=> String) => (Request[AnyContent] => Result)
```

So `f` is a function that takes a `=> String` and returns a function that takes a request and returns a result. As I indicated in my comment, have a look at [Need plain english translation of the following scala snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653873/need-plain-english-translation-of-the-following-scala-snippet/13656978#13656978) for an explanation of some of what's going on.

So why have `=> String` as the first argument versus just `String`? My guess is that it comes into play if you intended the user to pass a function that has its first argument *by name* (meaning it is evaluated every time it is needed).

So say you have a method `g`:

```
def g(s: => String): String => String = arg => s + arg
```

If you want to write a method `m` that takes the method `g` as an argument, then you need to write it like this:

```
def m(f: (=> String) => (String => String)) = f("a")("b")
m(g) // compiles
```

If you write it like this:

```
def n(f: String => (String => String)) = f("a")("b")
n(g) // does not compile
// found   : => String => (String => String)
// required:    String => (String => String)
```